# Matlab: Shell command with additional input

Tags: matlab, shell

I am calling 'phc.exe' with matlab in order to solve a complicated equation system. My operating system is Windows. I can call it using

```
system(['phc -b ' in_file ' ' out_file])
```

After I called the method I am promted to enter another 2 parameters. Basically it looks like this if I type it into the command line window:

```
>phc -b in_file out_file
>Which method do you want to use? (0,1,2,3,4): 3
>Do you want only real solutions (y/n):
```

The problem is I don't know how to do this in Matlab, but I need to do it as I have to repeat this a few hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a separate file and then use it as stdin using the shell's "<" operator.
Your code could be something like this:

```Matlab
file  = fopen('jobIn.txt', 'wt');

fprintf(file, '3\n');
fprintf(file, 'y\n');

fclose(file);

system(['phc -b ' in_file ' ' out_file ' < jobIn.txt'])
```

You can test if it works first on a terminal window (the "DOS" prompt). Also, take care with "\n" and "\r\n". You may have to test with both options to find out which one works.